# не могу запустить сокет-сервер на Ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

есть вот такой код:

```
$socket = stream_socket_server("tcp://127.0.0.1:8889", $errno, $errstr);
if (!$socket) {
   echo "socket unavailable<br />";
   die($errstr. "(" .$errno. ")\n");
}
```

если запускаю на Денвере, то все нормально работает, но если запустить на Ubuntu server, то выдает

```
socket unavailable
```

Не пойму в чём проблема. Ведь на Ubuntu по дефаулту открыты все порта? Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема и как её можно решить.

Comment: саму ошибку-то покажете?

Comment: Скорее всего это произошло из-за проблемы инициализации сокета. Ошибку в студию.

Comment: оно просто выводит в браузере socket unavailable
Address already in use(0). Это как я понимаю echo "socket unavailable<br />";
   die($errstr. "(" .$errno. ")\n");

Comment: socket unavailable Address already in use(0) - порт уже занят каким-то приложением

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> socket unavailable Address already in use(0).

Данная ошибка говорит о том, что порт `8889` используется другим процессом.

**Решение проблемы:**

1. "Убить" процесс и повторить попытку
2. Использовать другой порт

Comment: а можете подсказать команду для Линукса, по которой я могу проверить, какие порты заняты, или еще лучше, свободен ли указанный мною порт?

Answer (score 1):

Немного конкретизирую.

Взгляните, какой процесс занял данный порт, например:

```
$ netstat -tulpan| grep 8889
$ tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8889     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      <PID>/<process>
```

Вы увидите IP-адрес (`xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`), процесс (`<process>`) и его PID (`<PID>`), который занял порт. Далее, если вам нужно освободить порт, завершите приложение по его `<PID>`, например:

```
$ kill -9 <PID>
```

Перезапустите ваш скрипт/сервер.

P.S. В процессе отладки может случаться так, что процесс уже убит, а сокет (порт) еще используется, потому что таймаут перед освобождением порта еще не прошел. Тогда можно использовать опцию сокета (*socket options*) `SO_REUSEADDR`, либо уменьшить таймаут, чтобы можно было перезапускать сервер немедленно. [Подробнее](http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/addrinuse.html).